# Pegar titulo de postagem wordpress por SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress

Bom, preciso de algo mais ou menos assim:

```
$titulo = get_the_title( $post_id );
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,'>Episódio','>$titulo Episódio');
```

Sei que está completamente errado, mas talvez ajude a entender melhor. Preciso adicionar o titulo da postagem em uma linha da mesma por comando SQL (em todos os posts será feito isso).

Comment: Utilize [`$wpdb->update()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) ou [`$wpdb->query()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Running_General_Queries) para isso. Dessa forma a alteração será aplicada de uma só vez. Acho que é isso, caso não seja, seria legal exemplificar.

Comment: Na verdade essa função que coloquei já atualiza tudo de uma vez. O problema real é que quero colocar o nome da postagem no meio dessa substituição, porém não sei como pegar o valor do titulo.